# Unwanted space above the texts with a special font

Tags: html, css, fonts

I downloaded a font from fonthub for a site I'm coding, except that after I added it, I found that there is an unwanted space above every text on my site.

Example with my font:
[image: hellix]

Example with arial:
[image: arial]

Here is the link to the police who have the problem: https://fontshub.pro/font/hellix-download

How can I edit the font in order to fix the unwanted padding? Are there any free/open-source solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Some fonts have unnecessary whitespaces that you might not want.

The only way to adjust it is by setting the `line-height` of your text.

You could add a `padding-bottom` to center the text, then reduce the `line-height`.

You can't really control that whitespace otherwise without editing the font.

Text with the font:

[image]

```css
    font-size: 58px;
    font-family: Hellix;
    background: red;
```

Text with edited `line-height` / `padding`:

[image: Text with edited line-height/padding]

```css
    font-size: 58px;
    font-family: Hellix;
    background: red;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 50px;
```

The highlighted height is the same, but the space it takes on your document gets reduced.